# How to retrieve URL off a button?

Tags: c#

```
<div id="song_html" class="show1">
    <div class="left">
        <!-- info mp3 here -->
        3.88 mb
    </div>
    <div id="right_song">
        <div style="font-size: 15px;">
            <b>Beatles - Hey Jude mp3</b></div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <div style="float: left; height: 27px; font-size: 13px; padding-top: 2px;">
                <div style="float: left; width: 27px; text-align: center;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPlayer(161498180, 'b7f231500894c321c0a7739802edff16965eb111', 'beatles', 'hey+jude')"
                        rel="nofollow" id="lk161498180" class="play_now">Play</a></div>
                <div style="margin-left: 8px; float: left;">
                    <a href="http://dc109.4shared.com/img/1038702204/8ffe01b/dlink__2Fdownload_2FxAdbDSb4_3Ftsid_3D20111224-60034-
                    aa918a50/preview.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color: green;">Download</a></div>
                <div style="margin-left: 8px; float: left;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showEmbed(161498180,
                    'b7f231500894c321c0a7739802edff16965eb111')" rel="nofollow" id="em161498180" class="embed">
                        Embed</a></div>
                <div style="margin-left: 8px; float: left;">
                    <a href="http://www.ringtonematcher.com/go/?sid=WDLL&artist=beatles&song=hey+jude"
                        rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color: red;" title="Send Beatles - Hey Jude Ringtone to your Cell">
                        Send Ringtone</a></div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="player161498180" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" class="player">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would love to know how to retrieve the link 'http://dc109.4shared.com/img/1038702204/8ffe01b/dlink__2Fdownload_2FxAdbDSb4_3Ftsid_3D20111224-60034-aa918a50/preview.mp3'.

I asked around other forums and people numerous times but I still do not understand/not working.

It is a must that I get it through class "show1" as there are other classes.

Comment: you want to retrieve it using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Did you really need to post all of that HTML just to ask this question? Couldn't you have created a small example that still has the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this often, you can use the third-party (open source) library HtmlAgilityPack and get your value using XPath (for which there are many resources online).

Once I create the `HtmlDocument` (by downloading the page using `HtmlWeb.Load`) I would use the following to get the URL:

`String theLink = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='show1']//a[.='Download']").Attributes["href"].Value;`

Comment: Do you have the link to HtmlAgilityPack? Also if I use that, would the user have to download it as well?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/. You would use it as a DLL, so yes, the user would need it (but you can include it in an installation file or use ILMerge (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630 - though I have no experience with this option). You can also just put the DLL in the same directory as your executable.

Answer (score 0):

If the only unique thing is the text, you can do it this way using jQuery:

```
var href = $('a:text("Download")').attr('href');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can do get it using an html-parsing, as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

simple example:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[.='Download']");
var link = nodes[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
```

I believe that you is getting this HTML from 4shared page, you can use the [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method from `WebClient` class for get the HTML.

there more easy way to do it,using the API.